# Find the roots of a given polynomial

Tags: polynomials, roots

Let $f=X^{10}-5X^{8}+a_{7}X^{7}+ a_6X^6+...+a_{1}X+a_{0}$ be a polynomial with real coefficients.
We are asked to determine its roots $x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{10}$, where $|x_{1}|\geq 3$ and $x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{10}\in \mathbb{R}$.

I know that $x_{1}+...+x_{10}=0$, $x_{1}x_{2}+...+x_{9}x_{10}=-5$ and $x_{2}^{2}+...+x_{10}^{2}\leq 1$, but I haven't found anything meaningful besides this yet.

Thank you!

Comment: How did you get the inequality ?

Comment: @Peter: $(x_1+...+x_{10})^2=x_1^2+...x_{10}^2+2(x_1x_2+...+x_9x_{10})$

Comment: Consider taking a look at the symmetric polynomials, and seeing what sort of things drop out.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "determine its roots"? What is your goal?

Comment: @AntonioVargas I need to find all the roots of the polynomial. That's my "goal" for this problem.

Comment: Then I am confused. I would be very surprised if you could write the roots down in closed form. Are you sure it's possible?